# How to output results all in one time at the end versus outputting them one by one when using a for loop?

Tags: c, loops, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    int n, i, input_cases,x;
    scanf("%d", &input_cases);
    float *results = malloc(input_cases*sizeof(float));

    for (x=0; x<input_cases; x++){
    float num[100], sum[2] = {0.0}, average[2] = {0.0};
    printf("Enter the total amount of numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {  /* validates input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%f", &num[i]) != 1) { /* validate input */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    /* sum/average 1st-half */
    for (i = 0; i < n/2; ++i){
        sum[0] += num[i];
        average[0] = sum[0] * 2 / n;
    }
    /* sum/average 2nd-half */
    for (i = n/2; i < n; ++i){
        sum[1] += num[i];
        average[1] = sum[1] * 2 / n;
    }
    if (average[0]>average[1]){
            results[x]=average[0];
            printf("%.6f\n", average[0]);
    }
    else{
            results[x]=average[1];
            printf("%.6f\n", average[1]);}
    }
    for (x=0; x<input_cases; x++){
        printf("%.6f\n", results[x]);
        free(results);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what my code does:

```
Input:  
2  
Enter the total amount of numbers: 10  
10  
8  
9  
15  
12  
2  
3  
8  
7  
11  
10.800000(This is the output)  
Enter the total amount of numbers: 4  
3  
3  
2  
1  
3.000000(This is the output)
10.800000(My output when i dynamically allocate an array to display everything at the end)  
0.000000(My output when i dynamically allocate an array to display everything at the end)
```

This is how i actually want it to look like:

```
Input:  
2  
Enter the total amount of numbers: 10  
10  
8  
9  
15  
12  
2  
3  
8  
7  
11  
Enter the total amount of numbers: 4  
3  
3   
2  
1  

Output:  
10.800000  
3.000000
```

How can I take what i got from my calculations and have them all output at the very end instead of outputting each one separately at the end of each calculation?

Comment: Save the answers in an array (which you may have to grow dynamically).  When you're all done, iterate over the array and print them all out.

Comment: @TomKarzes I've tried doing that but when i print out that array, my values turn to 0's. I know im doing something wrong when dynamically allocating it, but i dont know what....

Comment: You're doing something wrong, but I can't help without seeing the code.

Comment: @TomKarzes hold on, i will show you what i'm doing

Comment: @TomKarzes please check now, I've edited my code up top so you can see what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to read due to the lack of indentation and the odd positioning of closing braces.  It's not clear which code is part of which loop.  That having been said, it's clear that you're freeing `results` while it's still in use.  You need to move the call to `free` below the loop that uses the array.

Answer (score 1):

You should `free` an `array` after printing all the values of it. But you are making a wrong that is you `free` that `array` after printing the first value. I think you got the point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    int n, i, input_cases,x;
    scanf("%d", &input_cases);
    float *results = malloc(input_cases*sizeof(float));
    int increment=0;

    for (x=0; x<input_cases; x++)
    {
        float num[100], sum[2] = {0.0}, average[2] = {0.0};
        printf("Enter the total amount of numbers: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)    /* validates input */
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (scanf("%f", &num[i]) != 1)   /* validate input */
            {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        /* sum/average 1st-half */
        for (i = 0; i < n/2; ++i)
        {
            sum[0] += num[i];
            average[0] = sum[0] * 2 / n;
        }
        /* sum/average 2nd-half */
        for (i = n/2; i < n; ++i)
        {
            sum[1] += num[i];
            average[1] = sum[1] * 2 / n;
        }
        if (average[0]>average[1])
        {
            results[increment++]=average[0];
            printf("%.6f\n", average[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            results[increment++]=average[1];
            printf("%.6f\n", average[1]);
        }
    }
    for (x=0; x<input_cases; x++)
    {
        printf("%.6f\n", results[x]);
        //free(results);
    }

    free(results);
    return 0;
}
```